# Has RISC-V unaligned Operations and a DCAS?

Tags: assembly, riscv

Has RISC-V unaligned Operations and a DCAS, i.e. 16 byte CAS with 64 bit addressing ? Unaligned operations are important for i/O purposes. And a DCAS is needed for lock-free stacks. Lock-free stacks are used in all modern memory-allocators to handle back items deallocated in threads that didn't allocate them. I use unaligned accesses in C++ through memcpy() with the size of native types and because memcpy() is mostly intrinisc with modern compilers it is replaced with a single move on x86, although the actual access might be unaligned.

Comment: what did you see in the spec on this topic, I think it is covered.

Comment: According to the documentation it's unspecified if an implementation supports unaligned memory operations but if they might be very slow. If you look at this - https://godbolt.org/z/3ssd6P11f -, the code looks horrible, whereas x86 does a single load here. Is there any RISCV-specific compiler-option to make the compiler assume that the CPU has support for unaligned operations ? And I've no idea regarding the second question about DCASes.

Comment: Pretty much nothing supports [DCAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_compare-and-swap) (atomic RMW on two separate memory locations).  Are you sure you can't use DWCAS, a CAS on a single 16-byte memory location?

Comment: That's pettifogging.